# Converting Visual Studio Add-in to Extension package

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I have an Add-in that runs in VisStudio 2012 and VisStudio 2013.
It does not have any UI; it monitors and responds to focus events.

When I converted the add-in to an Extension package (starting with the template provided by the VS2013 SDK), it works as expected when I have a menu item.
However, until  the menu command is used, the package doesn't seem to get fully initialized.

How can I force the full initialization of the extension package when is has no UI?

Comment: In a nutshell, when does it need to be loaded? Is it looking for a certain type of file, certain type of project, something else? There's a number of ways to trigger on something, but it's best to scope it. Imagine if every extension loaded on VS startup... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, JM.  It needs to be loaded at VS startup -- it monitors the top level window for loss of focus by implementing IVsBroadcastMessageEvents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you *truely* need to be done on first load, then the proper way to do it is to register your package as an AutoLoad package like is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166762%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). There are a number of "contexts" you register for, so you can register for "solution exists" and "no solution" if you need it always.